# How would one merge threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a project where items are loaded in one thread then at the end they need to be accessed in the main UI thread (since that holds OpenGL context).

My question is, how does one merge a thread once one thread is completed?

Code example.

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            //Load stuff completed.
            otherClassMethod(Thread.currentThread(), new ResultInterface(){

                @Override
                public void completed(){
                    //Start App.
                }

            })
        }
    });

    public void otherClassMethod(Thread thread, ResultInterface resultInterface)
    {


        //Create stuff that needs open gl context.
        //.....
        //-- end create stuff.

        Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread()
        thisThread.merge(thread); //?? Where I'm stuck.
        ResultInterface.completed
    }
```

Comment: The method is called `join()`, not `merge()`. It's as simple as that :)

Comment: What do you mean by merge? You want the 2 threads to access the same data?

Comment: Though I'd probably steer clear of managing threads manually, take a look at [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead, it takes a lot of the hassle out of multithreading.

Comment: How would I implement join in this scenario, I'll take a look at executor service too.

Comment: You just call `thread.join()`, where `thread` is the thread whose termination you want to wait for.

Comment: Not sure about OpenGL type stuffs, but GUI libraries like Swing and SWT have methods to queue things to run on the UI thread.  In Swing, it's [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-)

Comment: The `Thread` class does not have a method called `merge()`.  Other people have suggested that maybe you meant `join()`, but you said, "I don't get it, otherThread?`  Maybe you should tell us what you think `thisThread.merge()` should do.

Answer (score 2):

To wait for another Thread to be finished, call `otherThread.join()`.
This is blocking the current Thread until the *otherThread* is finished.

EDIT (from your example):

```
public void otherClassMethod(Thread thread, ResultInterface resultInterface)
{
    //Create stuff that needs open gl context.
    //.....
    //-- end create stuff.

    thread.join();
    resultInterface.completed();
}
```

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns I included the method from your example.

Comment: This is working like a charm, still perplexed about how threads work behind the scenes though, some kinda map I'd guess?